# Nested, collapsible checkbox inside dropdown with dynamic data-target?

Tags: javascript, python, flask, bootstrap-4

Using Bootstrap 4, I'm trying to achieve this structure inside a [Dropdown](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/dropdowns/)

```
[] Level 1
  [] Level 2
    [] Level 3
```

where the items are checkbox inputs and are [collapsible](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/collapse/). Here is a minimal, working example of what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <button id="dropdownButton' class='btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
    Dropdown
  </button>
  <form class="dropdown-menu">
    <ul id="level-1">
      <li class="dropdown-item">
        <label data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#level-2">
          <input type="checkbox"> Level 1
        </label>
        <ul id="level-2" class="collapse">
          <li class="dropdown-item">
            <label data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#level-3">
              <input type="checkbox"> Level 2
            </label>
            <ul id="level-3" class="collapse">
              <li class="dropdown-item">
                <label>
                  <input type="checkbox"> Level 3
                </label>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </form>
</div>
```

I'm using `form` to prevent the dropdown from closing when clicking a label. The problem seems to be the `data-target` and/or `id` values being dynamic (passed through a flask context).

For example:

```
<form class='dropdown-menu' aria-labelledby='{{ id }}' {% include 'fields/attrs.html' %}>
  <ul id='level-1-{{ id }}'>
    {% for title in dropdown_menu_items.values() %}
      <li class='dropdown-item'>
        <label class='form-check-label' data-toggle='collapse' data-target='#level-2-{{ id }}-{{ loop.index }}'>
          <input class='form-check-input' {% if title.provider_title_id %}name='{{ name }}'{% endif %} type="checkbox" {% if title.provider_title_id %}value='{{ title.provider_title_id }}'{% endif %} {% if title.checked %}checked='checked'{% endif %} />{{ title.title }}
        </label>
        <ul id='level-2-{{ id }}-{{ loop.index }}' class='collapse'>
...
```

[image]

I tested to make sure it "works" with static values like `level-2` and `level-3` and it does. Is there a way around this or am I just missing something obvious?

TL;DR - expand/collapse isn't working when assigning `id` and `data-target` through the flask context; only the `level-1` element is visible.